# select top N dynamically with N from the same select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a procedure that tries to insert samples in a table for each Agent, the # of samples for each agent varies based on some calculation

```
Declare @samplesize int
Declare @Top int
set @samplesize=0

;WITH DataToInsert AS
(
    Select AgentID, Surveys, LOB,(case when day(getdate())<4 then 3 else (day(getdate())) - (Surveys*3) end) SampleSize from Current_Agent_SurveyCount_HSI Where surveys<8 
)

--Insert Into Survey_Source_New (LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp])  
--Select top 5 ss.LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp]  
--From Survey_source_Level1 ss
--inner join DataToInsert du on ss.AgentZID=du.agentID
--where flag is null and du.samplesize>6
--order by newid()

Insert Into Survey_Source_New (LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp])  
Select top (@Top) @Top=du.samplesize,ss.LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp]  
From Survey_source_Level1 ss
inner join DataToInsert du on ss.AgentZID=du.agentID
where flag is null and du.samplesize<7
order by newid()
```

The error that I get here is

> *Msg 4115, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
>   The reference to column "samplesize" is not allowed in the argument of the TOP clause. Only references to columns at an outer
>   scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here.*

Is there a workaround for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to do essentially the same thing:

```
WITH DataToInsert AS
(
    Select AgentID, Surveys, LOB,(case when day(getdate())<4 then 3 else (day(getdate())) - (Surveys*3) end) SampleSize from Current_Agent_SurveyCount_HSI Where surveys<8 
)
Insert Into Survey_Source_New (LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp])  
    select LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp]
    from (Select ss.LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],
                 row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
          From Survey_source_Level1 ss inner join
               DataToInsert du on ss.AgentZID=du.agentID
          where flag is null and du.samplesize<7
         ) t
    where seqnum <= du.sample_size
```

You might be able to simplify this a bit, but I don't know if `flag` is coming from du or ss.

Answer (score 0):

I have an added scenario over the same question.
I made some changes to the existing  solution, the scenario is :
I get a list of Agents everyday and have to send each Agent a set of random Surveys, the count depends on some calculation for each agent.

```
--Get Agent List
;WITH AgentsList AS    
(    
    Select AgentID, Surveys, LOB,(case when day(getdate())<4 then 3 else (day(getdate())) - (Surveys*3) end) SampleSize     
    from Current_Agent_SurveyCount_FIOS Where surveys<8     
)
--Get All the Surveys for each Agent
, AgentSurveys AS
(
    select ss.LOB, ss.CenterName, ss.CallDate, ss.AgentZid, ss.TN, ss.Ticket, ss.RecordingID, ss.Cycle, ss.[TimeStamp],ss.Flag,AL.samplesize 
    from Survey_Source_Level1_Sri ss
    inner join AgentsList AL on ss.AgentZID=AL.agentID
    where flag is null 
    GROUP BY ss.LOB, ss.CenterName, ss.CallDate, ss.AgentZid, ss.TN, ss.Ticket, ss.RecordingID, ss.Cycle, ss.[TimeStamp],ss.Flag,AL.samplesize
)
--Mark random ranking for each survey
Select LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],samplesize,    
             rank() over (partition by agentzid order by newid()) as seqnum    
      From AgentSurveys
      group by LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],samplesize      
      order by agentzid,seqnum,tn
```

Now from the last query i get a table like

[image]

I require the N number of rows from each group where N comes from SampleSize column.

Comment: select LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],samplesize,seqnum
    from
(Select LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],samplesize,    
             rank() over (partition by agentzid order by newid()) as seqnum    
      From AgentSurveys
      group by LOB, CenterName, CallDate, AgentZid, TN, Ticket, RecordingID, Cycle, [TimeStamp],samplesize      )
      t
    where seqnum <= samplesize
      order by agentzid,seqnum,tn

Comment: This is working for the problem but what is the performance implication of the query?